# access args in render function in django

Tags: python, django, render

I'm using Django and can't access the argument (args) which I pass with my render method. I get the error: TemplateSyntaxError at /app/.
Could not parse the remainder: '['messages']' from 'args['messages']'

Views:

```
def index(request):
messages = ["This is message1", "This is message2"]
args = {'messages': messages}

return render(request, 'app/index.html', args)
```

Index html file:

```
{% for message in args['messages'] %}

<div class="live_message">
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

What is going wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're calling "args," Django calls the "context."

You don't need to refer to context items as dictionary keys.  So rephrasing your template tag like this should be all you need to make it work:

`{% for message in messages %}`

Comment: Well i'll be damned, it did work. Why does it work though? Does Django convert the dictionary to multiple lists in the render function? I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when I am able to.

Comment: Template tags are a language abstraction that look like Python but don't follow all of its conventions, so things like dictionary access don't work like you'd expect. Top-level key-value pairs within the context ("args") are referred to by key alone. The dev docs are worth reading so you know what you can and can't get away with during rendering: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/